# compare two variables in a text file

Tags: vbscript

I have a text file with multiple lines every two lines has the foillowing information:

Hostname, IP

IP, Hostname.Domain

What I would like to do is compare line one hostname and line two hostname. If they match I want to copy the hostname to a new text document.

I am new to scripting and would appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

if you use .split("\n"), it will give you an array that contain lines

```
contentLines = content.split("\n");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sN6XT/

Than just loop through the array for odd (or even) index, use regex to find  the line you want

Hope it helps :D

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set infile  = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\input.txt")
Set outfile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\output.txt")

Do Until infile.AtEndOfStream
  hostname1 = Trim(Split(infile.ReadLine, ",")(0))
  fqdn = Split(infile.ReadLine, ",")(1)
  hostname2 = Trim(Split(fqdn, ".")(0))
  If LCase(hostname1) = LCase(hostname2) Then outfile.WriteLine hostname1
Loop

infile.Close
outfile.Close
```